# Sitecore, BrainJocks Score Search Result Component shows empty tiles

Tags: brainjocks-score

Currently, i am exploring Brainjocks score components, available for Sitecore products, in one of my project. I am using few search components like search results, live search result and search suggestion, provided with this tool.

When i was searching any text, it was showing no search results. i modified the value of **Remove empty titles** to false in the search result rendering components, then it stared displaying the empty titles in the search results and search suggestion components according to the search result count.

Now, the question is,

Why am i not able to see the tiles with values but empty titles?

Am i missing anything here? Any advise would really be appreciated.

Comment: did the answer help? If not can you add more details to your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here are possible causes and things you can look into:

1- The search result tile is not setup on the rendering parameters of your component

2- The Search Result Tile is not present in the web database. If that's the case try to publish and validate whether it is present in the web db

3- The tiles are not being indexed. You can use any tools like Luke or Powershell Extensions to query your index and validate whether your tile is present on the index. If that's the case try to rebuild your indexes